# Add the correct MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers

I have a trigger that should work, but it does not work.

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE `refresh` VARCHAR(256);
    SET `refresh` = concat((SELECT `refresh` FROM `mobile_app_drivers` WHERE `id` = 1), '&');
    UPDATE `mobile_app_drivers` SET `refresh` = @refresh WHERE `id` = 1;
END
```

When it is executed, the cell `**refresh**` still broadcasts an empty string.

**// HOW I CREATE IT**

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `SET_UNIQUE_KEY`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `SET_UNIQUE_KEY` AFTER UPDATE ON `mobile_app_orders` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE `refresh` VARCHAR(256);
SET `refresh` = concat((SELECT MAX(`refresh`) FROM `mobile_app_drivers` WHERE `id` = 1), '&');
UPDATE `mobile_app_drivers` SET `refresh` = @refresh WHERE `id` = NEW.driver;
END
```

I need, when any record from the table is updated, then a new substring was added from the value `refresh` from the table `mobile_app_drivers`.

Thank you!

Comment: This is not how trigger is defined. You need to define on what action should this trigger, eg: `before insert`, `after update` etc

Comment: i updated the post

Comment: I added example how i create a trigger

Comment: Why do you use `@refresh`. It is session variable and has not been defined before. So it will be considered empty only.

Answer (score 0):

- You are using session variable `@refresh`. However, you have not defined it anywhere. So it will considered empty only.
- I modified your trigger to make it more clear and logical to follow. Declared a new variable `new_refresh` and we can set its value using `Into` clause inside a Select statement.
- Now, call the update statement.
- Also, you need to redefine Delimiter to something else (eg: $$), instead of (;).
- At the end, redefine the DELIMITER to ;

You can modify your Create Trigger statement to as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `SET_UNIQUE_KEY` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `SET_UNIQUE_KEY` AFTER UPDATE ON `mobile_app_orders` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE new_refresh VARCHAR(256) DEFAULT '';

SELECT CONCAT(MAX(`refresh`), '&') INTO `new_refresh` 
FROM `mobile_app_drivers` 
WHERE `id` = 1;

UPDATE `mobile_app_drivers` SET `refresh` = new_refresh WHERE `id` = NEW.driver;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a variable?  Just do:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `SET_UNIQUE_KEY`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `SET_UNIQUE_KEY` AFTER UPDATE ON `mobile_app_orders`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE mobile_app_drivers CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT MAX(refresh) as max_refresh
            FROM mobile_app_drivers
            WHERE id = 1
           ) mad1      
        SET refresh = concat(mad1.max_refresh, '&')
        WHERE id = NEW.driver;
END;
DELIMITER ;
```